# static constant referencing to parent variable

Tags: c++, oop

Lets say you want to use the same memory that a parent class does but would like a more fitting name for its new function. This is achieved like this (for example *SOCKADDR* from winsock):

```
class Parent{
    int a;
};

#define myA a;
class Child: public Parent{
    void print(){
        cout<<myA;
    }
};
```

---

Much like static const instead of a define - is there a C++ specific alternative of creating this reference?

Comment: I've never seen anything like this, but I don't go looking for good practices in win32 code.  I do look at win32 code for what NOT to do though :p

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions as C. Thanks.

Comment: An awful solution to an non-existing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be:

```
class Child: public Parent
{
     int& myA() { return a; }

     void print()
     {
        cout << myA(); 
     }
     void DoSomethingElse()
     {
        myA() = 10;
     }
};
```

Comment: myA is not an alias.. it's a function... and that too, only a getter function!

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry. I just took the code (thought it was the one from the question) and changed it so that it did what I intended. Now I see i took it from your reply. I will remove the comment :-)

Comment: But the question remains same. It's not a "reference". You cannot use it to set the value.

Comment: @Nawaz Please correct me if I am wrong but the poster asked for a way to be able to use "a more appropriate name" in the derived class. I admit calling the getter does not look as pretty but in my opinion is better than resorting to the preprocessor or aliasing through a reference. But that is just me...

Comment: @Nawaz it's still a relatively clean way to solve this, and hence a good suggestion. You could also make it return a reference.

Comment: @asveikau and @ds27680: What is the problem with reference as I did?

Comment: @Nawaz Even if didn't down vote your answer I find it has several problems. For one you pay the price associated with having an extra attribute (that takes up memory) as member of the class just to have a "better name" in the derived class. If you think about it if you use this "technique" on a large scale (i.e. imagine classes derived from Child, or imagine Parent has 3-4 variables) it can get confusing pretty fast. If I would have to choose between your solution and the preprocessor one presented in the question, to be honest I would chose the preprocessor one.

Comment: As ds pointed out it gets bad on a large scale, but I understand that some may prefer it and that it is a perfectly viable c++ solution. The trade-off being more code - but that is actually the normal oop giveaway. I have marked it as the answer because this solution wont take any more proc steps because of inlining nor memory.

Answer (score 0):

Define a reference like this, and initialize it in the initializer-list!

```
class Child: public Parent
{
     int& myA;
     Child() : myA(Parent::a) //<-- note this!
     {
     }
     void print()
     {
        cout<<myA; //myA is just an alias of a!
     }
};
```

Comment: This method will render the object un-assignable.

Comment: @Downvoters: How does this make sense if you don't specify the reason?

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev Well at least I had a good laugh today thanks to you. So +1 from me :-).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, however, when I added const int ref it still took an additional 4B for the pointer. The reference is also resolved at runtime, but could easily be when linking. I also tried short, but than the compiler added additional 2bytes for what I assume was padding. I'm just going to write a note in the docs and hope for the best...

Comment: This effectively requires space. References are semantically aliases, and in some situations the compiler can actually treat them as such, but when dealing with a reference as a member attribute of a class, the cost is going to be equivalent to a pointer.

Comment: You changed the size of the class.

Comment: 2byte explenation: 2(short)+4(reference)+2(padding)